# Importing data from CSV, XML or Json files to solr using dataimport

Tags: json, solr, import-from-csv

I am trying to import data from files like CSV, XML and Json to solr core, I am new to solr so this might be a straightforward to some but for me I have tried many online suggestions but not getting the desired result.

So I have a json file and I have enabled dataimport by adding the following requestHandler to solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler  name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">solr-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

And in the solr-data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource name="dfs" type="FileDataSource"/>
<document>
    <entity name="sourcefile" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" fileName=".*" rootEntity="false" baseDir="${solr.install.dir}/example/exampledocs">
        <entity name="entryline" processor="LineEntityProcessor" url="${sourcefile.fileAbsolutePath}" rootEntity="true" dataSource="fds" separator=","/>
    </entity>
</document>
```

The updated version:

```
    <dataConfig>
     <script><![CDATA[
    function CategoryPieces(row) {
      var pieces = row.get('manu_id_s').split('/');
      var arr = new Array();
      for (var i=0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
        row.put('manu_id_s' + i, pieces[i].trim());
        arr[i] = pieces[i].trim();
      }
      row.put('manu_id_s', (pieces.length - 1).toFixed());
      row.put('manu_id_s', arr.join('/'));
      row.put('manu_id_s', arr.join('/'));
      return row;
  }
     ]]></script>
  <dataSource type="FileDataSource" />
  <document>
    <entity
      name="document"
      processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
      baseDir="${solr.install.dir}/example/exampledocs/khaled"
      fileName=".*.xml$"
      recursive="false"
      rootEntity="false"
      dataSource="null">
      <entity
      name="test"
        processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
        transformer="script:CategoryPieces"
        url="${document.fileAbsolutePath}"
        useSolrAddSchema="true"
        stream="true">
      </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

And I have added a json, csv and xml files to the path, in the ui of solr when I use the dataimport it says that e.g. Requests: 0 , Fetched: 26 , Skipped: 0 , Processed: 0 and nothing in the logs, can someone advice how to add the data in the file to solr?

Here is my sample data in the xml file:

```
<add>
<doc>
  <field name="id">USD</field>
  <field name="name">One Dollar</field>
  <field name="manu">Bank of America</field>
  <field name="manu_id_s">boa</field>
  <field name="cat">currency</field>
  <field name="features">Coins and notes</field>
  <field name="price_c">1,USD</field>
  <field name="inStock">true</field>
</doc>

<doc>
  <field name="id">EUR</field>
  <field name="name">One Euro</field>
  <field name="manu">European Union</field>
  <field name="manu_id_s">eu</field>
  <field name="cat">currency</field>
  <field name="features">Coins and notes</field>
  <field name="price_c">1,EUR</field>
  <field name="inStock">true</field>
</doc>

<doc>
  <field name="id">GBP</field>
  <field name="name">One British Pound</field>
  <field name="manu">U.K.</field>
  <field name="manu_id_s">uk</field>
  <field name="cat">currency</field>
  <field name="features">Coins and notes</field>
  <field name="price_c">1,GBP</field>
  <field name="inStock">true</field>
</doc>

<doc>
  <field name="id">NOK</field>
  <field name="name">One Krone</field>
  <field name="manu">Bank of Norway</field>
  <field name="manu_id_s">nor</field>
  <field name="cat">currency</field>
  <field name="features">Coins and notes</field>
  <field name="price_c">1,NOK</field>
  <field name="inStock">true</field>
</doc>

</add>
```

Now the data returned from the query looks like:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1547556805546"}},
  "response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "manu_id_s":"boa",
        "id":"USD",
        "_version_":1622731088078045184},
      {
        "manu_id_s":"eu",
        "id":"EUR",
        "_version_":1622731088081190912},
      {
        "manu_id_s":"uk",
        "id":"GBP",
        "_version_":1622731088081190913},
      {
        "manu_id_s":"nor",
        "id":"NOK",
        "_version_":1622731088082239488}]
  }}
```

Comment: Could you share your sample data file?

Comment: @mysterion well I have kind of approched what i want but still not as desired please look at the updated solr-data-config.xml, this update get processed but the returned data from the query only contains some data and not all of it, can you advice what am I doing wrong? you can find the sample data in the updated question